# ImageView in CardView not show radius on Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cardview

Here my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/catalog_item_card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/test_merchant_preview"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here result on Andrdoid 5.0+

[image: radius]

As you can see the ImageView success show with radius. OK.

Now I run app on Android 4.3.

And here result:
[image: no_radius]

As you can see the ImageView show without radius.
Why?

Comment: it won't work below android 5.0 . you have to do it through using drawables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ImageView in CardView not show radius on Android 4.3

**`CardView`  elevation only work on android 5.0 and above**

`CardView` uses elevation property on Lollipop for shadows and falls back to a custom emulated shadow implementation on older platforms.

Due to expensive nature of rounded corner clipping, on platforms before Lollipop, `CardView` does not clip its children that intersect with rounded corners. Instead, it adds padding to avoid such intersection

more information [read here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)