# How can I create a CardView and ImageView with a rounded border?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make the following design:

[image: my design]

But I do not know how to round up the ImageView and vertical lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

> minSdkVersion 16
>     targetSdkVersion 28

**EDIT:**

According to document: [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView)

> Due to expensive nature of rounded corner clipping, on platforms
>   before Lollipop, CardView does not clip its children that intersect
>   with rounded corners. Instead, it adds padding to avoid such
>   intersection (See setPreventCornerOverlap(boolean) to change this
>   behavior).

I wrote this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/test_ex"
                app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_left="40dp"
                app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="40dp" />


            <View
                android:layout_width="4dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

And the result in the Android 4.3 emulator:

[image]

How can I do the clipping? What is the best solution?

Comment: Can you show your current result in a screenshot?

Comment: @Phil I do not know how ImageView has a radius.

Comment: You can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775

Comment: @beigirad it is circular image view. I wan radius corner left imageview in CardView

Comment: so you must create a custom viewGroup!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/image_"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:rotation="15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_">

    </View>


       <View
           android:layout_width="5dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#be0202"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#be0202"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Result :

[image: Cardview with rounded corner ImageView]

Comment: Thanks. it's true code, but not work on pre api 21 version. please see: https://i.imgur.com/qYErAJt.png  -

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347411/imageview-in-cardview-not-show-radius-on-android-4-3

Comment: For API below 21 you need to use some library which can round corners of an image . Try this library https://github.com/sparrow007/CircularImageview

Answer (score -1):

Already answered by [charan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5633108/charan-ghumman)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="26dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_8">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_tag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="HELLO!"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQhfb.png)